# Failed to detect New Relic instrumentation. error in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, newrelic

I'm trying to create a test app using the New Relic library in Eclipse on Ubuntu, Android 4.2.2, New Relic SDK 2. When I run the app I get following error:

```
E/com.newrelic.agent.android(31733): Failed to detect New Relic instrumentation.
```

Something likely went wrong during your build process and you should contact support@newrelic.com.

I followed the New Relic SDK installation tutorial for the example app exactly, but I still get this error, and no data is sent to New Relic.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is apparently the compiler platform version. After switching to Android 4.1.2 everything went perfect.
I contacted New Relic on this matter but didn't got any reply yet. Will update the answer when i do.

Comment: Did you ever get a response from New Relic about this?

Comment: @MichaelHerbig No, I did not!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error until I upgraded Eclipse to Juno. Apparently the New Relic plugin isn't compatible with older versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Windows 8 64-bit. But I was already compiling with the Android API 18 compiler.

My problem was solved by launching Eclipse with the -vm switch to point to a Java JDK 1.6, 64-bit install. (I was running off a JRE 1.7 32-bit install before.)

`C:\java\bin\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin"`

Comment: This year, I had the same problem. This fix wasn't enough though. I also had to update the New Relic plugin, then _remove_ the old JAR and re-install via the plugin. (Upgrading the JAR via the plugin didn't work.) Still had to run Eclipse with the JDK though.

Answer (score 1):

i've found that as i load other projects in to my environment that i get this error as i try to launch them. it could be just a simple example that comes with a library. my solution to this has been to right click the project and hit the new relic button to install it in the project. all this does is simply insert their jar and link it in... pretty harmless. there is probably a better way but this works for now.

Comment: New Relic has released a fix for this issue (as of version 3) so you shouldn't have to install the jar in apps you're not instrumenting to get them to compile in Eclipse.

Comment: @asm I think it was an Android build tool update that enabled JAR libs to be automatically included in parent apps if the library is referenced only in the shared library. (It wasn't New Relic.) So make sure you have updated Android build tools, or do what MrTristan suggested as a workaround.